# problem calling wikirandom api using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to call this api http://www.wikirandom.org/json

Using this code -

```
    $.getJSON('http://www.wikirandom.org/json', function(data) {
  //do somthing
   });
```

I'm not getting a response. if I go to the url directly it works fine.

if I use the following in the head of my doc it calls no problem. -

```
 <script src="http://www.wikirandom.org/json?&callback=functionThatalertsdata&pages=1&languages=en" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in Javascript.